# Character Output - PHP Includes

Tags: character, currency, symbols

Here the problem - my html doc type heading is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

If I write some text which includes the '£' sign it displays correctly.

If I include a php script which uses the '£' sign I get strange character output:

�

I know that I can replace the £ with the html characters code '£' but since my site is large that is not practical.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use the `utf8_encode` function?

Comment: Again i'm going to have to trawl through ym site to make changes. One solution is to remove the utf-8 encoiding from the html heading but then it screws up any characters when retrieved from the database...