# using PHP include and symbol outputs

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm building a website for a friend using Wordpress. There is one particular element he is going to need to update and he's not used to code so I have created a file that he can edit without getting involved in wordpress.

In wordpress I call this file using PHP include which works wonderfully until there are any £ symbols in the file. At this point the £ symbol gets replaced with a ? in a square thats been rotated 45 degrees.

I have looked on this site and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007526/character-output-php-includes), the problem being, that doesn't help me.

I have tried replacing the £ symbols for `&pound;` & `&#163;` both of which give the same output.

Anyone got any ideas?

EDIT: As requested;

```
<p class="menu_item">Americano - £2.00<br><span id="item_description">A double espresso stretched</span></p>
```

there are various lines like the one above in the file being called. I then call the file in wordpress using `<?php include './wp-content/menu_content.txt'?>` - I have tried calling it as a txt file, php and html.

Comment: Please paste your code.

Comment: This could be a problem with the character encoding, try to use other character encoding that supports these characters (like UTF-8 for example), and see what happens.

Comment: @DemVoids, Thank you for the reply. Do you know how I achieve that in wordpress? or do you meant to set the character encoding in the source file?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not very familiar with wordpress, but check if you can change the character encoding of the parent page (since the included page shouldn't contain headers in your case).

Comment: Is the header `<!doctype html><head><meta charset="UTF-8">...</head>` ??

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not a problem with wordpress but rather with web server that tries to serve this site in some other encoding. Can you provide response/request headers and a raw html page heading?